# Automate image size in R shiny leaflet pop-up

Tags: r, image, shiny, popup, leaflet

I have a `shiny app` which I run in 3 separate tabs in R Studio:

- **Global tab:**

```r
    library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)
    
    country = c("Russia", "Mongolia", "China")
    latitude = c(64.9, 47.01, 35.6)
    longitude = c(91.2, 98.1, 95.6)
    photo = c("russia.png", "mongolia.png", "china.png")
    text = c("This is Russia", "This is Mongolia", "This is China")
    countries = cbind.data.frame(country, latitude, longitude, photo, text)
```

- **UI tab:**

```r
      ui = fluidPage(
      hr(),
      tags$p("Please click on the button to see the data:"), 
      actionButton(inputId = "go",
                   label = "Button!", align = "center"),
      hr(), 
      leafletOutput("basicMap", height = "500px")
    )
```

- **Server tab:**

```r
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      
      readData = eventReactive(input$go, {
        countries
      })
      
    
      output$basicMap = renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(data = readData()) %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          addCircleMarkers(data = readData(), lng = ~ longitude, lat = ~ latitude,
                           
                           popup = ~ paste0("<strong>","", readData()$country, '</strong>',"<br>",
                                          "<br>", 
                                          "<img src = ", readData()$photo, ">",
                                          "<br>",
                                          "<strong>","", readData()$text, '</strong>',"<br>"
                           ))
        })
          }
```

This runs fine, and in each pop-up, I have a title and some text which correspond to the relevant line in the data frame from which that pop-up is derived. This is also true of the image. However, I am unable to automate the image size:

[image]

Please could someone help me do this? Thank you!

Comment: you could adjust  the size: `"<img src = ", readData()$photo, " width = 200>"`